# Reported coverage from DJANGO is different from the HTML generated by Coverage.py

Tags: python, django, code-coverage

So, I'm using the coverage.py console utility, as follows (on a django project):

```
$ coverage run --source='.'  --omit='*__init__*, *manage.py*' ./manage.py test
```

And as a final result on the coverage reported right there on screen (by django's test runner), I get 27%, but then I create the HTML report like this:

```
$ coverage html -d ./folder
```

And there I get 8%.

Any idea why I'm getting different numbers for what should be the same report?

Comment: "coverage run" doesn't report results on the screen, so something else is doing it.

Comment: You are correct, apparently the django test runner also reports coverage, which is different from what coverage.py reports.